# Nginx with Supervisor keep changing status b/w Running and Starting

Tags: nginx, supervisord

Here's a preview of the status running `supervisorctl status` every 2 seconds:

```
[root@docker] ~ # supervisorctl status
nginx                            RUNNING    pid 2090, uptime 0:00:02
[root@docker] ~ # supervisorctl status
nginx                            STARTING   
[root@docker] redis-2.8.9 # supervisorctl status
nginx                            RUNNING    pid 2110, uptime 0:00:01
```

Is this a normal thing for nginx to respawn every few seconds ? Knowing that nginx is setup to be run in the background with this setup:

```
[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx
stdout_events_enabled=true
stderr_events_enabled=true
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Its been a long time, but it might help someone else... set `daemon off` in your nginx config. Supervisord requires processes not to run as daemons.

You can also set it directly for the supervisor command:

```
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

Comment: Great answer, been spending ages trying to figure this out!

Comment: You can also  switch daemon mode off as part of the command invokation: `/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"`

Comment: thanks for this answer, my issue was that nginx tried to rebind to the ports it bound to already, which then junked my error log. Adding -g "daemon off;" fixed it